# Where Are Ventura System Settings Icons Located?

Tags: macos, icon, system-settings, ventura

I'm creating a menu bar interface to Ventura's System Settings.  Where do the icon resources (e.g., Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Network, Notification, etc.) reside?

[image]

I've checked all the usual Resources folders to no avail.

Comment: It already has a menu list of the categories, in the View menu. And you can access many settings from other menulets, either by Option clicking, or a menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in SF Symbols. See [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols) on Apple's Developer site.

As this is veering into development I'll say no more!